# Create a Sprite from raw RGBa data

Tags: html, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs, sprite-sheet

I take several snapshots from playing video on canvas and thus getting raw RGB images into memory.

In the documentations its states that Sprite class accepts a Spritesheet instance only.

- Is there any way to create a Sprite from raw RGBa?
- Or maybe convert that raw data into separate Bitmap data and then put into the Sprite sheet somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to construct a `SpriteSheet` using your `Image` instances. See the docs for details:

http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheet.html

SpriteSheet supports multiple source images, so each frame could be a separate image.

Alternatively, if you want to combine a bunch of frames into a single, more efficient source image and produce a `SpriteSheet` from it, you should look at using `SpriteSheetBuilder`. There are some simple examples of this with EaselJS, and of course docs:

http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheetBuilder.html